# Copy an entire file to a specific location

Tags: c++

I have a problem whit copying a file from one location to another. I don't want to copy the content of the file, i need to copy the entire file also his name.
Something like this : 
source= "C:\src\test.txt"
destination="C:\dest" //and in folder dest should appear the file test.txt
It's easy to copy the content of file but whit this i don't have any ideea and the internet doesn't help me. 
If can someone help me it will be just awesome. Thx.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
 {
 size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

char buf[BUFSIZ];
size_t size;

FILE* source = fopen("data.in", "rb");
FILE* dest = fopen("data.out", "wb");

// clean and more secure
// feof(FILE* stream) returns non-zero if the end of file indicator for stream is set

while (size = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZ, source)) {
    fwrite(buf, 1, size, dest);
}

fclose(source);
fclose(dest);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: How are you copying the file now?

Comment: I pasted in the question my code..but ther i copy the content and not the file

Comment: Well, in this code you are reading from "data.in" and writing to "data.out". If you replace the former with "C:\\Source\\file.txt" and the latter with "C:\\Dest\\file.txt" you get what you want, don't you?

Comment: Yes, it works but is very slow when i copy large file. Has anyone a better solution?